# Convert SQL query to linq with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

Can anyone help, I'm having trouble translate the following query to linq:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DATENAME(Month, bo.u_datadesc)),
    DATENAME(Month, bo.u_datadesc),
    DATEPART(Month, bo.u_datadesc),
    bo.u_rpmotori 
FROM 
    bo 
WHERE
    (bo.u_rpmotori = 'John' OR bo.u_rpmotori = 'Michael') 
    AND bo.boano = '2016' 
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(Month, bo.u_datadesc),
    DATEPART(Month, bo.u_datadesc),
    bo.u_rpmotori 
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(Month, bo.u_datadesc)
```

The main problem here is the count. I want to count the number of results in a month grouped by name and month. I tested the raw query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio and it works fine.

Thank you

Comment: We'll be happy to help you with this, but we won't do it for you.  Do you have any C# models?  Can you paste your LINQ attempts into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leave the date name to the client side and use something like.

```
    (from bo in db.bo
     where
       (bo.u_rpmotori == "John" || bo.u_rpmotori == "Michael") &&
        bo.boano == '2016'
     group bo by new
     { 
         Month = bo.u_datadesc.Month,
         bo.u_rpmotori

      } into g
     orderby g.Key.Month
     select new
     {
         Count = g.Count() ,
         Month = g.Key.Month,
         Motorista = g.Key.u_rpmotori
     }).ToList()
```

This should give you similar results, unless your data can contain records with null dates. In that case, I think your sql will return zero for the count, whereas the linq code will return the actual number of records.

Comment: count=g.key.Count(); g.key  doesn't contain a reference to Count();

Comment: Sorry. Should be just Count = g.Count()

Answer (score 0):

here is an attempt:

heres an attempt :

```
(from bo in db.bo
 where
  (bo.u_rpmotori == "John" || bo.u_rpmotori == "Michael") &&
   bo.boano == '2016'
  group bo by new
  {
    Count = bo.u_datadesc.Month.ToString().Count(),
    Month = bo.u_datadesc.Month,
    bo.u_rpmotori

  } into g
  orderby g.Key.MonthNumeber
  select new
  {
    Count = g.Key.Count,
    Month = g.Key.Month,
    Motorista = g.Key.u_rpmotori
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not sure if i should open a new question but I kind of have a follow up question. How is it possible to return the count for every month of the year, event if the count is 0. For example, right now i can have Februay: count=3 but I would like to return January: count=0; February:count=3; March: count=0; etc...! Is this possible with linq?